# Old behaviour for list-buffers (C-x C-b) with two windows

Tags: emacs

I upgraded emacs some time ago (now Debian 24.5+1-6+b2), and I noticed that the behavior of C-x C-b (list-buffers) changed when two windows are active: Before, it would always show the list of buffers in the other window (the one the cursor is not currently in). Now, it only shows the list of buffers in the other window if the buffers refer to the same file. If they refer to different files, it shows the list of buffers in the *same* window (the one the cursor is currently in).

This is really irritating, as I'm used to the old behaviour. How can I get the old behaviour back? (And is this a bug, and if not, what was the rationale for the change?)

Comment: Instead of using `(defun list-buffers (&optional arg) "Doc-string . . ."" (interactive "P") (display-buffer (list-buffers-noselect arg)))` consider adding a `t` like this:  `(defun list-buffers (&optional arg) "Doc-string . . ."" (interactive "P") (display-buffer (list-buffers-noselect arg) t))`  Does that resolve your issue?

Comment: The last paragraph of the doc-string for `display-buffer` in the Emacs *master branch* states:  "*The ACTION argument to ‘display-buffer’ can also have a non-nil and non-list value.  This means to display the buffer in a window other than the selected one, even if it is already displayed in the selected window.  If called interactively with a prefix argument, ACTION is t.*"

Comment: @lawlist: I actually don't define list-buffers anywhere in `.emacs`, and I didn't change the binding anywhere. If you can point me to the file where I have to make this change, or better, if you can explain to me what I need to add to my `.emacs` file, I can try out your suggestion. I'm not very familiar with the elisp stuff, I just want the old behaviour back. :-)

Comment: You can try it out first without making any changes by pasting the second function into your `*scratch*` buffer and place your cursor immediately after the last closing parentheses and type:  `M-x eval-last-sexp`  Then run some tests using `C-x C-b` and see if it makes the desired improvement you are seeking.  If you like it, then paste the entire function into your `.emacs` file and restart Emacs.  I don't have earlier versions of Emacs installed, so I won't be able to do an analysis as to what was then versus what is now, and why that change occurred.

Comment: @lawlist: Thanks, it worked. Do you want to turn the comment into an answer? BTW, the definition is in `buff-menu.el.gz`

Comment: 1. If it's not in the NEWS file and you can't find an existing bug report, then sure -- go ahead and raise it as a bug. 2. I would encourage anyone using `list-buffers` to remap the binding(s) for that to `ibuffer` instead -- it is *much* more capable and useful.

Comment: @phils: I just tried `ibuffer` out of curiosity, and it has the same behaviour as `list-buffers` wrt. the two windows ... And I mostly use the buffer menu to switch buffers, so I don't really need other capabilities. The color markup looks nice, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `list-buffers` utilizes the function `display-buffer` from `window.el`, and the second and third optional arguments (i.e., ACTION and FRAME) are `nil` because nothing has been specified for them.  The last paragraph of the doc-string for `display-buffer` in the Emacs master branch states: "*The ACTION argument to ‘display-buffer’ can also have a non-nil and non-list value. This means to display the buffer in a window other than the selected one, even if it is already displayed in the selected window. If called interactively with a prefix argument, ACTION is t.*"

The original function for `list-buffers` defined in `buff-menu.el` contains a line that looks like this:  `(display-buffer (list-buffers-noselect arg))`.  What this answer does is add a `t` so that the second optional argument for `display-buffer` -- i.e., ACTION -- is non-nil and non-list.  That achieves the behavior described in the above-mentioned doc-string.  The new function looks like this, and it can be pasted directly into the `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(defun list-buffers (&optional arg)
  "Display a list of existing buffers.
The list is displayed in a buffer named \"*Buffer List*\".
See `buffer-menu' for a description of the Buffer Menu.

By default, all buffers are listed except those whose names start
with a space (which are for internal use).  With prefix argument
ARG, show only buffers that are visiting files."
  (interactive "P")
  (display-buffer (list-buffers-noselect arg) t))
```